# Strings in external JSON file with templates

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have a javascript file that I'd like to pull the strings out of, mostly to make editing them easier (and perhaps for localization down the road). In the past, I've put the strings into a `strings.json` file and just read them from there. However, for my current use case, I'm using template literals (e.g. `` `Hello ${name}!` ``).

Ideally I'd do something like this:

```
// strings.json
{
  "greeting": `Hello ${name}`
}
```

...

```
// myfile.js
alert(
  getString("greeting", { name: "Camden" });
);
```

I can worry about the specifics of `getString` and parsing the template string... my question is more about best practices & prior art (so-to-speak) when it comes to problems like this.

Thanks!

Comment: it can't be JSON at that point, but a file of named/exported literals should fit in the same places.